# Specify the length of index keys in CakeSchema

Tags: sql, cakephp, indexing, database-schema

If you are going to define a index key using the InnoDB engine of MySQL, you could get this error message:

```
"Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes"
```

This is actually warned in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

The solution is pretty straightforward. You just have to specify a key length in SQL, e.g.:

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE INDEX (`name`(50), `active`)
```

But when dealing with CakePHP schemas and fixtures, I could not have found a way to specify this, thus my tests fail.

An alternative solution could be deleting the `'indexes'` array of the fixture. But it would be nice to do it through CakeSchema.

Is it possible to do this with the actual CakeSchema in CakePHP 2.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope it appears that is not supported within the CakeSchema :(

http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/dbo-source#l-3103

You'll have to rely on custom SQL to support it.

I use the CakeDC Migrations plugin to manage schema changes (up and down).

https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations

With that, I have used the after() callback to trigger custom alter statements

```
var $migration = array(
    'up' => array(
        'create_field' => array(
            'utils' => array(
                'indexes' => array(
                    // can not add here, because we can't specify column
                    // length - see after() callback
                    //'key_val' => array('column' => array('key', 'val'), 'unique' => 0),
                    'key_misc1' => array('column' => array('key', 'misc1'), 'unique' => 0),
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'down' => array(
        'drop_field' => array(
            'utils' => array(
                'indexes' => array(
                    'key_val',
                    'key_misc1',
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
function after($direction) {
    if ($direction=='up') {
        $sql = 'ALTER TABLE `utils` ADD INDEX `key_val` (`key`, `val`(128));';
        $Util = ClassRegistry::init('Util');
        $Util->query($sql);
    }
    return true;
}
```

```